# iOS UInavigation bar to uitableviewcontroller not as rootviewcontroller in appdelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I'm loading a table view control by pressing a button in view controller
.The code in my Viewcontroller.m is

```
-(IBAction)go:(id)sender{

TableViewController *sec=[[TableViewController alloc]init];

sec.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];
}
```

Now my table view controller loads..Now i need to add a navigation bar which have title and back button which loads view controller.I also want to know how to assign action to that back button where i can load view controller

I tried out in google which all makes tableviewcontroller as root view controller where in my app rootviewcontroller is view controller..Is there a way to add that in my xib or by programmatically.

Help pls..

Comment: Do you want TableView Controller along with Navigation Controller is that what you are looking for ? Thanks :)

Comment: You have to be bit more explanatory in your Qs so that you can better answer . Thanks :)

Comment: @SALMAN:yes...but nothing to be changed in app delegate..

Comment: @SALMAN:Because i don't want to change rootviewcontroller because my rootviewcontroller is view controller..

Comment: But still you can hide navigation bar from top if you dunt want that on your RootViewController ,doesnt adding navigation Controller from app delegate doesnt make sense :S

Comment: i had tried the code UINavigationController *navigationController; navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init]; [self.view addSubview:navigationController.view]; and got navigation bar but it scrolls along with tableview and it displayed in mid of tableview and it hides the content...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
-(IBAction)go:(id)sender{

    TableViewController *sec=[[TableViewController alloc]init];

    UINavgationController *nav = [[UINavgationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sec];
    nav.modalTransitionStyle=UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:nav animated:YES];
```

}